# Java fileinput (read and write) to a file looping thru each line

Tags: java, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

I have this method that access a exisitng file, loop thru each line and replace (string to string) a certain line if the condition is met:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

private void UpdateConfig() {
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("c:\\user\\config.properties");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (strLine.contains("FTPDate=2014/07/01 00:59:00")) {
                System.out.println("FILE " + strLine);
                strLine.replace("FTPDate=2014/07/01 00:59:00", "FTPDate=2014/09/10 00:00:00");
                //strLine.replace("((19|20)\\d\\d/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])) ([2][0-3]|[0-1][0-9]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]:([0-5][0-9]|[6][0])", "2014/09/10 00:00:00");
                System.out.println("FILE " + strLine);
            }
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

In the sysout it seems its being replaced:

```
FILE FTPDateTejas=2014/07/01 00:59:00  
FILE FTPDateTejas=2014/09/10 00:00:00
```

But when I check the file, the date still stays the same. Am I missing something? anyone knows what I missed out? thank you

Comment: `replace` changes the string in memory but not to disk. You need to open another file for writing and write each line out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing:

`strLine = br.readLine()` it loads the next line from the `BufferedReader` into memory. This means that you have your data on disk and in memory and that those two are not linked to each other in any way. When doing modifications on `strLine` I believe you have in your code:

`strLine = strLine.replace("FTPDate=2014/07/01 00:59:00", "FTPDate=2014/09/10 00:00:00");`

As `replace` doesn't modify the contents of the objects on which it is being called but returns a new `String` objects (Strings are immutable). So what that does it creates a new object but does not modify your on disk data (as I said, it's not linked to it any more!).

You could think "ok then how do I link those two and override the file in place?". Well Java does provide random file access [as described in the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html) but the only thing you can do with it is `modify` characters at a certain position, you cannot insert things in the middle. So what you would have to do is read the rest of your file, make your modification and then append that rest of the file, yes you need to shift things in case your new string with which you are substituting would be shorter/longer than what you are replacing.

That's why an easier solution would be to:

1. open a new file to write to
2. write line by line to it (the strings **after** the replace)
3. delete the old file and rename the new file

Without copying the file the code would look something like this:

```
private void UpdateConfig() {
    File fstream = new File("c:\\user\\config.properties");
    File file = new File("c:\\user\\config.properties-new");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle
    }
    try (FileReader in = new FileReader(fstream);
         FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile())) {

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
             BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (strLine.contains("FTPDate=2014/07/01 00:59:00")) {
                    System.out.println("FILE " + strLine);
                    strLine = strLine.replace("FTPDate=2014/07/01 00:59:00",
                            "FTPDate=2014/09/10 00:00:00");
                    //strLine.replace("((19|20)\\d\\d/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])) ([2][0-3]|[0-1][0-9]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]:([0-5][0-9]|[6][0])", "2014/09/10 00:00:00");
                    bw.write(strLine);
                    System.out.println("FILE " + strLine);
                }
            }
        }
        // copy files here
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle
    }
}
```

There might be some logical/syntactic problems as I was writing in in a plain text editor. I modified the code a bit to use Java 7's try-with-resources, which is a cleaner way of closing resources than what you were doing - in your code when an exception would be thrown the stream might not had been closed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation with a sample code that works properly. really appreciate it. :)